# qdpm (project manager) fails rendering attached image previews

Tags: php, project-management

The problem is the following, if you purchase the qdpm "extended" addon (the paid version of qdpm) you notice that the attached images is possible to download, but not possible to preview on the "View" button.

The render image shows "**image cannot display because contain errors**".

Is very annoying that I can't contact with the technical support of this software but it's open source on PHP (Symphony) and I can modify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question because I achieve to solve the error.

You need to modify this file:

`qdpm_root/core/apps/qdPMExtended/modules/attachments/actions/actions.class.php`

Search `executeView()` function and replace this code:

```
if($size = getimagesize($file_path))
{
  $filename = substr(str_replace(array(' ',','),'_',$attachments->getFile()),7);

  header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $filename . '"');                          
  header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");                  
  ob_clean();
  flush();

  readfile($file_path);
}
```

with this:

```
if($size = getimagesize($file_path))
{
  $filename = substr(str_replace(array(' ',','),'_',$attachments->getFile()),7);

  header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $filename . '"');                          
  header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");     

  readfile($file_path);             
  ob_clean();
  flush();
}
```

And it works like a charm.